# Command line option to open mac formatted file in Vim

Tags: vim, file-format

I have a file with mac format, I know I can use `:e! ++ff=mac` to change to the correct fileformat. What I'd like to know is if there is a command line option I can pass when I open the file to open it directly with the correct fileformat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* do this using the command line, try:

```
$ vim -c "set fileformat=mac"
```

`-c <command>` executes  before loading the first file. As jammessan has noted, this will only affect the first file that is loaded, subsequent files will require that you change `fileformat` for each buffer.

If that doesn't work, you can also try:

```
$ vim -c "e ++ff=mac"
```

But it's better to set this up in your .vimrc on that machine:

```
set fileformats=mac,unix,dos
```

specifies which formats to try when starting a new buffer. This also can influence what `fileformat` is chosen for existing files.

See `help file-formats`, `:help 'fileformat'` and `:help 'fileformats'` for more details.

Comment: There is no `fileformat=mac` command.  `-c` is run after the first file is loaded, and since `'fileformat'` is buffer-specific this will only work if that first file is the one that needs the option set.

Comment: simple omission. Edited and added the _set_. Thanks @jamessan.

Comment: Did you try using my amended command line: `vim -c "set fileformat=mac"`? Also try `vim -c "e ++ff=unix"` if the former doesn't work. I edited my answer to include that.

Comment: `vim -c "e ++ff=mac"` that was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution would be to make Vim automatically recognize files in that format.  You can do this by updating the `'fileformats'` option in your `~/.vimrc`

```
set fileformats=unix,dos,mac
```

This will make Vim check all three formats when determining which format a file is in.

Comment: What did `:set ff?` say after adding that and opening the file in a new vim session?