# Try/catch item with strange syntax

Tags: scala, try-catch

Strange syntax in this code fragment:

```
var result =
  try {
     Process(bl).!!
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      log.error(s"Error on query: ${hql}\n")
      "Etc etc" + "Query: " + hql
  }
```

Why not using separator like `,` or `;`  after `log.error(s"...")`?

The `catch` statement is returning one or two values?

PS: there are a better [Guide tham this one](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/try-catch-finally.html), with all Scala syntax alternatives?

Comment: Why would you put a separator? - I mean, the syntax is pretty clear to me. The `catch` is a **block** _(similar to the one of a `match`)_. And all the `try` must return a value, in this case both branches return a **String**.

Comment: Hi @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, when I am using modern Javascript  (ES6+) the `x=>y` is evident, and `x=>y z` is an error. I not see "both branches".. Where the Scala  language Guide say that there are `y,z` and not only `y`?

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean? `try block catch (macth expr block)+` is the syntax of the try _expression_. As any other _expression_ in the language, it has to return a value. The return type of a try _expression_ is the **LUB** between the return type of the **try-block** and all **catch-macth-blocks** _(in this case there is only one, and in this case both return **Strings**)_. - Also, as any other block in the language, you may use `;` to separate statements, but they are optional if you only write one statement per line. - I still do not understand why this confuse you.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks the regular expression, `try block catch (macth expr block)+ `  this is near  the answer that I was looking for, and the `+` make all difference. There are, in [this official Guide](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/try-catch-finally.html), an example of `(macth expr block)+` with two blocks, but you and the Guide not show the block syntax of my question. On my question we have **only one block**, like  `case foo: FooException => handleFooException(foo); handleBarException(bar)`   that is strange.

Comment: Not really, because each match is followed by a block. If you want for your own sanity you could do this: `} catch { \n case e: Exception => {\n log(...) \n "ect" \n } \n }` _(the `\n` are there to show you where to break the line if you copy and paste, since comments don't preserve that)_. As you can see, we started a new block after the match. Is just, that the compiler allows you to omit these brackets and most people would do so.

Comment: Thanks for all @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez! As in the second part of  [@Mario's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59501992/287948), your explanation of `catch {case e: x=>{stm1; stm2} }` solve the problem, that is, the internal block syntax now make sense.  I added a phrase about `catch` to avoid confusion and downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Newline characters](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#newline-characters) can terminate statements

> `semi ::= ‘;’ |  nl {nl}`
>
> Scala is a line-oriented language where statements may be terminated
>   by semi-colons or newlines. A newline in a Scala source text is
>   treated as the special token “nl” ...

IMHO, newline character `\n` is just as good of a statement terminator as semicolon character `;`. However, it may have an advantage over `;` in that it is invisible to humans which perhaps has the benefit of less code clutter. It might seem strange because it is invisible, but rest assured it is there silently doing its job delimiting statements. Perhaps it might become less strange if we try to imagine it like so

```
1 + 42'\n'  // separating with invisible character \n
1 + 42;     // separating with visible character ;
```

Note that we must use semicolons when writing [multiple statements on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21355965/5205022)

```
log.error(s"Error on query: ${hql}\n"); "Etc etc" + "Query: " + hql
```

---

Addressing the comment, AFAIU, your confusion stems from misunderstanding how [pattern matching anonymous functions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions) and [block expressions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#blocks) work. Desugared handler function

```
case e: Exception =>
  log.error(s"Error on query: ${hql}\n")
  "Etc etc" + "Query: " + hql
```

is equivalent to something like

```
case e: Exception => {
  log.error(s"Error on query: ${hql}\n"); // side-effect statement that just logs an error
  return "Etc etc" + "Query: " + hql;     // final expression becomes the return value of the block
}
```

Hence, *"one block with two branches into it"* is **not** the correct understanding, instead there is only a **single** code path through your particular function.

Comment: Thanks Mario! Well, you say that we are separating commands (it is equivalent to  `command1; command2`), so it is not a second function's or method's parameter... A second problem to understand this syntax is this split into two branches, where the Scala Language Guide say that there are more tham one branch?

Comment: @PeterKrauss Ah, I get why you are confused now, you believe `catch` is a function. It is not, it is a built-in _expression_ of the language, similar to `match`, they both use **pattern matching**.

Comment: @MarioGalic yes, my confusion is near it...  At [this official Guide](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/try-catch-finally.html), we see an example of  with  two macth expr. blocks, but the Guide not show the block syntax of my question. On my question we have **only one block** with two branches into it, inside the block... Like  `case foo: FooException => {handleFooException(foo); handleBarException(bar) }`   that is strange.  Summary: after your good explanations  I was expected   `x=>y; x=>z` **not** `x=>(y;z)`... Where Scala Guide say that these two syntaxes are equivalent?